# Css menu Doesnt open with the :active line

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanted to make a sliding menu for a site for fun but for some reason I cant do it with css I can do it another way but its bizarre why it doesnt work this way

```
    <div class="top">
        <div class="solmenuac" onclick="toggleMenu()">
            <img src="images/menu.png" class="menuxx" >
            <img src="images/menuhover.png" class="menuyy">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="solmenu"></div>


<script>
function toggleMenu() {
  var menu = document.querySelector('.solmenu');
  menu.classList.toggle('solmenu-active');
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

## And my css code

```
}
:root{
    --d1: #000000;
    --d2: #111111;
    --d3: #232323;
    --d4: #343434;
    --d5: #464646;
    --d6: #575757;
    --d7: #696969;
    --d8: #7A7A7A;

    --dblue: #22223B;
    --lblue: #4A4E69;
    --lila: #9A8C98;
    --greyf: #C9ADA7;
    --icec: #F2E9E4;
}
body{
    background-color: var(--d3);
}
.top{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 7vh;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: var(--d2);
}
.solmenuac{
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    width: 5vh;
    height: 5vh;
    margin: 1vh 0 0 1vh;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.menuyy{
    display: none;
}
.solmenuac:hover .menuxx{
    display: none;
}
.solmenuac:hover .menuyy{
    display: block;
}
.solmenu{
    position: fixed;
    width: 15vh;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    display: none;
}
.solmenu-active {
    display: grid;
    z-index: 10;
}
</style>
```

I double checked the code the file and image locations and I wrote a js but that didnt work as well I dont know if it matters but I use firefox I guess I can do it another way with js but Im really curious why this way doesnt work I also intend to merge this with a php code

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: You have an extra `}` at the beginning of the CSS. That will cause everything after it to be ignored.

Comment: but the css works I can do anything else and deleting it did not fix the issue

Comment: There's nothing in the `.solmenu` div, what 's supposed to display when you add the `solmenu-active` class?

Comment: It was supposed to be a menu like youtube's  side menu I gave the measurments but still doesnt work  am I missing something here

Comment: I know what a menu is. Can you post the actual code, including the menu contents, in a Stack Snippet so we can try to run it?